# Flex 3 to Flex 4 warning

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

Hello i'm migration flex 3 to flex 4 and i have 1 warning and i try to fix it but nothing work.

The warning is: data binding will not be able to detect assignments to toplevelapplication

In flex 3 i had application.Application and now i have FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication

I have 1400 FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication and +- 150 .AS files.

I tried to use Application(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication), mainAPP(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication), and nothing works, The only think that clean the warning is if i add [Bindable] public var myApplication:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication; to all the .AS files but when i run the project and try to log in the application i have Action Script Errors

Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: 1400 references to topLevelApplication sounds like you may have a problem with the use of encapsulation in your code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. The clean way to access the Application is via FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.

```
[Bindable]
public var app:mainApp = mainApp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication); // fail fast to find erros
```

Should to the work, if that is not the case, you seem to access that instance too early. You should bootstrap the Application (and move on from there) after FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE has been dispatched. Also, i suggest that if you introduce a field in your classes like

```
private const app:mainApp = mainApp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication); // fail fast to find errors

protected final get app():mainApp { return app; }
```

to access the field cleanly in your application and avoid too many heavy dependencies to you application.

PS: Class names, even if suffixed .mxml should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Don't forget to cast topLevelApplication as an Application; as I believe it returns a generic object.

Comment: Tnx for the answer so insted of putting myApplication:Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication i need to put myApplication:mainapp = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication??

Comment: Trying to fix this in so big project is a pain in the a** :( and the strange thing is that all project works with this warnings all thing with no problems.